# store a series of data in ontology model via sparql update

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology

I have a large data (integers and float numbers for certain variables e.g Actual_Production_Time =[4,8,11,25] ) and they keep on increasing with new updates. So my question what is the preferred way to store such data in a model from the below two or any other if anyone can recommend. 
1st:

```js
PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#>
INSERT DATA
{ 
  test:Actual_Production_Time test:hasValue_ROB1 4
}
```

Here hasValue_ROB1 is 'Data type property' while 4 is just one integer. So every time I have new value, I run this update. and the values keep on stacking up. the answer is as below

```js
test:Actual_Production_Time
        a                    test:KPI_Variables , owl:NamedIndividual ;
       test:hasValue_ROB1   "4", "8,"11","25" ;
```

2nd method is:

```js
PREFIX test:<http://www.semanticweb.org/muhammad/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-14#> 
insert {
[] test:Kpi_Variable ?s;
test:hasValue_ROB1 ?p; 
test:hasTime ?now.
} 
where {values (?s ?p ) 
{(test:Actual_Production_Time 4)} 
bind (now() as ?now)}
```

following is the way it get stored

```js
[ test:Kpi_Variable    test:Actual_Production_Time ;
  test:hasTime         "2017-09-04T11:30:48.293+03:00"^^xsd:dateTime ;
  test:hasValue_ROB1  4
] .
```

Right now I am using the second method because of the time stamp attached with each blank node, so it gives me a chance to extract data based on time.

P.s. I am sorry the question gets a bit lengthy and subjective.

Comment: Ok, but what is the question now? I mean, of course, both ways are different, the second one contains an additional timestamp for insertion of the value. So the answer is for sure driven by your requirements, in particular, whether you need the timestamp later on, or not.

Comment: the question is which one of them is best practice to follow. Time stamps may not be important in some cases

Comment: As I said, this totally depends on your further use-cases. Obviously, when you need the timestamps even only for a small part of the application, it's still necessary and you can't avoid it. On the other hand, the query becomes more expensive as you have to get the values from the blank nodes.